# Send an email from an API endpoint using Django Rest Framework and Angular

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I'd like to send an email once a POST has been successfully completed. It seems to make sense that the email would be done with a signal. I can write my own, as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals

However, what I can't figure out is:

1. Does Django Rest Framework support signals (why wouldn't it, it's just Django)
2. What do I listen to to send the custom signal? What is the sender?

Suggestions welcome.

Also, is anyone doing this with Angular? Is there a simple way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Maybe on success of POST you can HttpResponse to a certain `view` that  you then use for sending the email?

Comment: Did you find a good Design Pattern? What would be the best solution for sending email? (maybe redefining post_save hook)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, DRF supports signals.

I don't have a good answer for question 2, mainly because I think the best place to do this is in the **post_save** method of your class. That way, you are sure your object was created, you have access to the object and to the request and you don't need to bother implementing signals (which would probably require another class just for email sending).

Answer (score 6):

Old question for an old version of Django, but if anyone comes across it... It's not necessary to use signals. Django now has the built-in function `send_mail`. Here's the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/

So you would use that function to create and send an email. It can even accept an HTML template as the message argument and populate it w/ Django data, which is nice.

So you'd define a function that included this method, for example:

```
def email_client(request):
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    client = Client.objects.get(id=id)
    msg_html = render_to_string('templates/email.html', {'client': client})
    template_email_text = ''
    return send_mail('Lelander work samples', template_email_text, 'test@emailsender.com', ['test@emailrecipient.com'], html_message=msg_html, fail_silently=False)
```

And include that function in your DRF API view in `post`:

```
class ClientList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

queryset = Client.objects.all()
serializer_class = ClientSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    email_client(request)
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```